# Can you reload a React Native app from React Native Debugger?

Tags: react-native, react-native-debugger

I've just switched from debugging my React Native app in the browser using the console to [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger). In the browser, there is a button to reload the app which is very useful and something that I need to do a lot. Now using React Native Debugger I can't find a way to reload the app which means I need to shake the device (very annoying).

I've searched the docs but can't find way of doing it.

Is there a way I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a reload can be done I think. Right click -> reload Js.
You can find this under the shortcut references: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/shortcut-references.md